# How to reset a character array to 0/NULL in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a program to count letters in every word of a given string and append the count to the word.

Example - I/p: The cake O/p: The3 cake4

In my logic, I want to reset a counter variable named `icnt` of type integer(which is done) & and an array named `temp` of type character(which is not working).
I did some research on StackOverflow and implemented `memset` to reset but looks like it didn't work for me!

Kindly correct my program if there are mistakes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void fun(char*,char*);

char ch[50];
char temp[10]={0};

int main()                                                      
{                                                               

        printf("Enter string :");
        scanf("%[^'\n']s",&ch); 

        fun(ch,temp);
}

void fun(char *ptr,char *tptr)
{
        int icnt = 0;

        while(*ptr!='\0')
        {
                if(*ptr!=' ')
                {
                        *tptr = *ptr;
                        tptr++;
                        icnt++;
                }
                else if(*ptr==' ')
                {
                        printf("In IF bcoz of space\n");

                        printf("%s %d\n",temp,icnt);
                        icnt = 0;
                        //temp[10] = {0};      //*
                        memset(temp,0,10);     //*
                        //Tried reseting in both the above ways *
                }

                ptr++;

        }

        if(*ptr=='\0')
        {
                printf("%s%d\n",temp,icnt);
        }


}
```

Output of the above program: The34

Looks like nothing is getting stored the 2nd time in the temp variable

Excepted output: The3 cake4

Comment: The function `fun` is writing the found word in `*tptr` not directly in `temp` variable. So once you find a word you should reinitialize `tptr` to `&temp`.

Answer (score 2):

> `printf("%s %d\n",temp,icnt);`
>
> `temp[10] = {0};`

Your function takes `temp` as argument and accesses that global variable directly. This is not a bug up to here but it makes no sense: The function will only work if the `tptr` argument has a certain value. So why using an argument at all?

> `temp[10] = {0};`
>
> `memset(temp,0,10);`

Because your function overwrites the content of that array with the line `*tptr = *ptr` it is ***not*** neccessary to initialize the `temp` array at all!

Instead you only have to ensure that the last value in the array is a zero. You do this the following way:

```
*tptr = 0;
printf(...,temp,...);
```

Theoretically you could also use `memset` but this is not neccessary and will take more computation time.

> Output of the above program: The34

Your program increments `tptr` (`tptr++`) but it never re-sets it!

Therefore the `temp` array has the following content:

```
/* Before the first printf: */ "The\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
/* After memset: */ "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
/* Before the second printf: */ "\0\0\0cake\0\0\0"
```

If your input is longer than 10 characters your program may even crash because it writes to memory it is not allowed to write to.

`printf` will write an empty string the second time because the first character of the `temp` array is NUL...

> Kindly correct my program if there are mistakes.

I would do the following changes:

I would use two different variables for `tptr`:

```
void fun(char *ptr,char *output)
{
    char *tptr = output; /* here */
```

Instead of referencing `temp` in the function I would reference the argument which I would never modify. Before `printf` I would write the NUL byte to the end of the array and after `printf` I would reset the write pointer (`tptr`):

```
*tptr = *ptr;  /* This remains tptr; does not become output */
*tptr++; /* This also */

...

*tptr = 0; /* This is new: Ensure the last byte is NUL */
printf(...,output,...); /* Not test, but output */
tptr = output; /* This is new: Reset the write pointer */
/* memset(...) - No longer needed */
```

Comment: Should suggest to use `sizeof`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If the user passes `temp` as argument (and does not access the array directly) he or she cannot use `sizeof` to get the array size (`sizeof(output)` will return the size of pointers, not the size of the array the pointer points to).

Comment: You  cite `memset(temp, 0, 10)` which could be `memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp))` when `temp` is an array like `char temp[10];`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This is correct. However I think that directly accessing `temp` from the function makes no sense because `output` (or `tptr`) is a function argument and I should not assume that the function argument has a certain value. What I could do is passing the array size as third parameter to the function... However: My solution does not use `memset` at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void fun(char*,char*);

char ch[50];
char temp[10]={0};

int main()                                                      
{                                                               

        printf("Enter string :");
        scanf("%[^'\n']s",ch); 

        fun(ch,temp);
}

void fun(char *ptr,char *tptr)
{
        int icnt = 0;

        while(*ptr!='\0')
        {
                if(*ptr!=' ')
                {
                        *tptr = *ptr;
                        tptr++;
                        icnt++;
                }
                else if(*ptr==' ')
                {
                    printf("In IF bcoz of space\n");

                    printf("%s %d\n",temp,icnt);
                    icnt = 0;
                    //temp[10] = {0};      //*
                    memset(temp,0,10);
                    tptr = temp; /* The tptr was not reinitialised to point to base address */
                    //Tried reinitialization in both the above ways *
                }

                ptr++;

        }

        if(*ptr=='\0')
        {
            printf("%s%d\n",temp,icnt); /* Here you are printing from the base address.*/
        }
}
```

The print was done from the **base address** of the array and the after reinitialisation the **tptr** was not set to point to the base address of the array. Code attached should work fine.

Comment: Yes pointer wasn't reinitialized ...your correction worked for me.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add  after "inct = 0;" the instruction : " tptr = temp;" because if you don't add it you will go out from the memory space of the table "temp". And you have also to add   "*tptr='\0' " just before "printf("%s %d\n",temp,icnt);".